# Get PDF attachments using Python

Tags: python, pdf

I admit that I am new to Python.
We have to process PDF files with attachments or annotated attachments. I am trying to extract attachments from a PDF file using PyPDF2 library.

The only (!) example found on GitHub contains the following code:

```
import PyPDF2

def getAttachments(reader):
      
      catalog = reader.trailer["/Root"]
      # VK
      print (catalog)
      
          # 
      fileNames = catalog['/Names']['/EmbeddedFiles']['/Names']
```

And the call is:

```
rootdir = "C:/Users/***.pdf"  # My file path
handler = open(rootdir, 'rb')
reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(handler)
dictionary = getAttachments(reader)
```

I am getting a **KeyError: '/EmbeddedFiles'**

A print of the catalog indeed does not contain EmbeddedFiles:
{'/Extensions': {'/ADBE': {'/BaseVersion': '/1.7', '/ExtensionLevel': 3}}, '/Metadata': IndirectObject(2, 0), '/Names': IndirectObject(5, 0), '/OpenAction': IndirectObject(6, 0), '/PageLayout': '/OneColumn', '/Pages': IndirectObject(3, 0), '/PieceInfo': IndirectObject(7, 0), '/Type': '/Catalog'}

This particular PDF contains 9 attachments. How can I get them?

Comment: @K J What is the easy way to extract the embedded objects? We would like to run at the top folder and process all PDF files in subfolders. For encryptions we use GhostScript but attachments and portfolios we process manually.

Comment: @K J Thank you, will check xpdf methods

Comment: xpdf is not very helpful. And the question remains: how to detect PDF attachments/annotated  attachments without Java/C++.

Comment: The new [PyPDF2 docs on annotations/attachments](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/reading-pdf-annotations.html#attachments) might be interesting

Answer (score 2):

### Later Edit

With the rebase of PyPDF (Back to Roots) replacing PyPDF2 this was closed out by  Add "reader.attachments" enhancement in **PyPDF 3.5.0 (Feb 2023) See**
https://github.com/py-pdf/pypdf/commit/5e792c2519f101045e512ec047ebfcaf5e87ee28

**Older Answer**
*Too Long for comments, and I have not tested personally this code, which looks very similar to your outline in the question, however I am adding here for others to test. It is the subject of a Pull Request https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/pull/440 and here is the  full updated sequence as described by Kevin M Loeffler in https://kevinmloeffler.com/2018/07/08/how-to-extract-pdf-file-attachments-using-python-and-pypdf2/*

*Viewable at https://gist.github.com/kevinl95/29a9e18d474eb6e23372074deff2df38#file-extract_pdf_attachments-py*

*Download as
https://gist.github.com/kevinl95/29a9e18d474eb6e23372074deff2df38/raw/acdc194058f9fa2c4d2619a4c623d0efeec32555/extract_pdf_attachments.py*

It always helps if you can **provide an example input** of the type you have problems with so that others can adapt the extraction routine to suit.

**In response to getting an error**
"I’m guessing the script is breaking because the embedded files section of the PDF doesn’t always exist so trying to access it throws an error."
"Something I would try is to put everything after the ‘catalog’ line in the get_attachments method in a try-catch."

Unfortunately there are many pending pull requests that were not included into PyPDF2 ***but are now included in new Re-Incarnation as PyPDF*** https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/pulls and others may also be relevant or needed to aid with this and other shortcomings. Thus you need to see if any of those may also help.

For one pending example of a try catch that you might be able to include / and adapt for other use cases see https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/pull/551/commits/9d52ef517319b538f007669631ba6b778f8ec3a3

Associated keywords for imbedded files apart from `/Type/EmbeddedFiles` include `/Type  /Filespec` & `/Subtype /FileAttachment` note the pairs may not always have spaces so perhaps see if those can be interrogated for the attachments

Again on that last point the example searches for /EmbeddedFiles as indexed in the plural whilst any individual entry itself is identified as singular

Comment: This doesn't work for most PDFs.

Answer (score 2):

I was also running into the same problem with several pdfs that I have. I was able to make these changes to the referenced code that got it to work for me:

```
import PyPDF2

def getAttachments(reader):
    """
    Retrieves the file attachments of the PDF as a dictionary of file names
    and the file data as a bytestring.

    :return: dictionary of filenames and bytestrings
    """
    attachments = {}
    #First, get those that are pdf attachments
    catalog = reader.trailer["/Root"]
    if "/EmbeddedFiles" in catalog["/Names"]:
        fileNames = catalog['/Names']['/EmbeddedFiles']['/Names']
        for f in fileNames:
            if isinstance(f, str):
                name = f
                dataIndex = fileNames.index(f) + 1
                fDict = fileNames[dataIndex].get_object()
                fData = fDict['/EF']['/F'].get_data()
                attachments[name] = fData

    #Next, go through all pages and all annotations to those pages
    #to find any attached files
    for page_object in reader.pages: 
        if "/Annots" in page_object:
            for annot in page_object['/Annots']:
                annotobj = annot.get_object()
                if annotobj['/Subtype'] == '/FileAttachment':
                    fileobj = annotobj["/FS"]
                    attachments[fileobj["/F"]] = fileobj["/EF"]["/F"].get_data()
    return attachments


handler = open(filename, 'rb')
reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(handler)
dictionary = getAttachments(reader)
for fName, fData in dictionary.items():
    with open(fName, 'wb') as outfile:
        outfile.write(fData)
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be improved but it was tested to work (using PyMuPDF).
It detects corrupted PDF files, encryption, attachments, annotations and portfolios.
I am yet to compare the output with our internal classification.
Produces a semicolon separated file that can be imported into Excel.

```
import fitz                      # = PyMuPDF
import os

outfile = open("C:/Users/me/Downloads/testPDF3.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
folder = "C:/Users/me/Downloads"

print ("filepath;","encrypted;","pages;", "embedded;","attachments;","annotations;","portfolio",  file = outfile)
enc=pages=count=names=annots=collection=''

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
    for file in files:
        #print (os.path.join(subdir, file))
        filepath = subdir + os.sep + file

        if filepath.endswith(".pdf"):
            #print (filepath, file = outfile)
            
            try:
                doc = fitz.open(filepath)
 
                enc = doc.is_encrypted
                #print("Encrypted? ", enc, file = outfile)
                pages = doc.page_count
                #print("Number of pages: ", pages, file = outfile)
                count = doc.embfile_count()
                #print("Number of embedded files:", count, file = outfile)     # shows number of embedded files
                names = doc.embfile_names()
                #print("Embedded files:", str(names), file = outfile) 
                #if count > 0:
                #    for emb in names:
                #        print(doc.embfile_info(emb), file = outfile)
                annots = doc.has_annots()
                #print("Has annots?", annots, file = outfile) 
                
                links = doc.has_links()
                #print("Has links?", links, file = outfile)
                trailer = doc.pdf_trailer()
                #print("Trailer: ", trailer, file = outfile)
                xreflen = doc.xref_length()  # length of objects table
                for xref in range(1, xreflen):  # skip item 0!
                    #print("", file = outfile)
                    #print("object %i (stream: %s)" % (xref, doc.is_stream(xref)), file = outfile)
                    #print(doc.xref_object(i, compressed=False), file = outfile)
                    
                    if "Collection" in doc.xref_object(xref, compressed=False): 
                        #print ("Portfolio", file = outfile)
                        collection ='True'
                        break
                    else: collection="False"
                    #print(doc.xref_object(xref, compressed=False), file = outfile)
                    
            except:
                #print ("Not a valid PDF", file = outfile)
                enc=pages=count=names=annots=collection="Not a valid PDF"
            print(filepath,";", enc,";",pages, ";",count, ";",names, ";",annots, ";",collection, file = outfile )                
outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a late reply, but i only started looking into this yesterday. I have used the PyMuPdf library to extract the embedded files. here is my code:

```
import os
import fitz

def get_embedded_pdfs(input_pdf_path, output_path=None): 
  input_path = "/".join(input_pdf_path.split('/')[:-1])

  if not output_path : 
    output_path = input_pdf_path.split(".")[0] + "_embeded_files/"

  if output_path not in os.listdir(input_path):
    os.mkdir(output_path)

  doc = fitz.open(input_pdf_path)

  item_name_dict = {}
  for each_item in doc.embfile_names():
    item_name_dict[each_item] = doc.embfile_info(each_item)["filename"]

  for item_name, file_name in item_name_dict.items():
      out_pdf =  output_path + file_name
      ## get embeded_file in bytes
      fData = doc.embeddedFileGet(item_name)
      ## save embeded file
      with open(out_pdf, 'wb') as outfile: 
        outfile.write(fData)
```

Answer (score 0):

**disclaimer**: I am the author of `borb` (the library used in this answer)

`borb` is an open-source, pure Python PDF library. It abstracts away most of the unpleasantness of dealing with PDF (such as having to deal with dictionaries and having to know PDF-syntax and structure).

There is a **huge** repository of examples, containing a section on dealing with embedded files, which you can find [here](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/borb-examples#510-working-with-embedded-files).

I'll repeat the relevant example here for completeness:

```py
import typing
from borb.pdf.document.document import Document
from borb.pdf.pdf import PDF


def main():

    # read the Document
    doc: typing.Optional[Document] = None
    with open("output.pdf", "rb") as pdf_file_handle:
        doc = PDF.loads(pdf_file_handle)

    # check whether we have read a Document
    assert doc is not None

    # retrieve all embedded files and their bytes
    for k, v in doc.get_embedded_files().items():

        # display the file name, and the size
        print("%s, %d bytes" % (k, len(v)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

After the `Document` has been read, you can simply ask it for a `dict` mapping the filenames unto the bytes.

Answer (score 0):

I found that most of these if not all have been deprecated and here's another example where chatGPT and Bing GPT fail. Even the pypdf documentation  https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/reading-pdf-annotations.html has errors, for example they introduce annotation then refer to annot, annotobj not defined and so on...

but I was able to get there by updating the code as suggested by pylance. In the end, it didn't work for me because the attachments were embedded as links, not attachments.  But in case it helps someone else.

```
import PyPDF2

def getAttachments(reader):
    """
    Retrieves the file attachments of the PDF as a dictionary of file names
    and the file data as a bytestring.

    :return: dictionary of filenames and bytestrings
    """
    attachments = {}
    #First, get those that are pdf attachments
    catalog = reader.trailer["/Root"]
    #print(catalog)
    try:
        if "/EmbeddedFiles" in catalog["/Names"]:
            fileNames = catalog['/Names']['/EmbeddedFiles']['/Names']
            for f in fileNames:
                if isinstance(f, str):
                    name = f
                    dataIndex = fileNames.index(f) + 1
                    fDict = fileNames[dataIndex].getObject()
                    fData = fDict['/EF']['/F'].getData()
                    attachments[name] = fData
    except:
        pass
    #Next, go through all pages and all annotations to those pages
    #to find any attached files
    for pagenum in range(0, len(reader.pages)):
        page_object = reader.pages[pagenum]
        
        #print(pagenum,page_object)
        if "/Annots" in page_object:
            for annot in page_object['/Annots']:
                annotobj = annot.get_object()

                try:
                    if annotobj['/Subtype'] == '/FileAttachment':
                        print("found fileattachment")
                        fileobj = annotobj["/FS"]
                        attachments[fileobj["/F"]] = fileobj["/EF"]["/F"].getData()
                except:
                    pass
    return attachments

handler = open("pathtoyourPDFdoc.pdf", 'rb')
reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(handler)
dictionary = getAttachments(reader)
for fName, fData in dictionary.items():
    with open(fName, 'wb') as outfile:
        outfile.write(fData)
```